# Запись в файл в цикле

Tags: массивы, php, файлы

Есть 332 файла с текстом, каждый по 8 MB. Нужно все их перебрать и записать данные по массивам в php-файлы.

Структура такова:
require/qq/ - главная папка, в ней лежат другие папки, названия которых содержатся в массиве $sets. В каждой из таких папок должны создаться php-файлы типа [001-500].php, также в каждой такой папке есть папка reg, в которой должны создаться php-файлы типа reg_[001-500].php.

```
$fn='this/_items.';
$sets=array('gf','tt','sb','hj','tg','ng','pu','as','fs','bf','yt','xz','rq','fs');
$entries=array();

for($i=1;$i<333;$i++){
/* ИМЯ ФАЙЛА */
    $number_length=strlen($i);if($number_length==2){$a='0'.$i;}elseif($number_length==1){$a='00'.$i;}else{$a=$i;}$filename=$fn.$a;
/* ИМЯ ФАЙЛА */

    $file=fopen($filename, "r");
    $f=file($filename);$last=array_pop($f); // last

    $k=0;

    while(!feof($file)){
        $k+=1;
        $ass=fgets($file);
        if($last==$ass){
            $old=$ass;
        }else{
            if($k==1){
                $ass=$old.$ass;
            }
        $ass_array=explode("EMP; (",$ass);
        $ass_arr=explode(',',$ass_array[1]);

        $ass_arr[0]; // fq_id
        $ass_arr[1]; // tq_id
        $ass_arr[2]; // lc
        $ass_arr[3]; // rq_id
        $ass_arr[4]; // en
        $ass_arr[7]; // es
        $ass_arr[10]; // ru
        $ass_arr[13]; // ua
        $ass_arr[19]; // pt
        $ass_arr[22]; // de
        $ass_arr[25]; // fr

            foreach($sets AS $u){
                if(!isset($entries[$u])){$entries[$u]=array();}
                if(!isset($entries[$u][$ass_arr[1]])){$entries[$u][$ass_arr[1]]=array();}
                switch($u){
                    case 'en':$lan=4;default;
                    case 'es':$lan=7;default;
                    case 'ru':$lan=10;default;
                    case 'ua':$lan=13;default;
                    case 'pt':$lan=19;default;
                    case 'de':$lan=22;default;
                    case 'fr':$lan=25;default;
                }
// ЗДЕСЬ НУЖНО ЗАПИСЫВАТЬ В ФАЙЛЫ 
                $set=$ass_arr[0].'='.$ass_arr[3].'='.$ass_arr[$lan];
                array_push($entries[$u][$ass_arr[1]],$set);
 // ЗДЕСЬ НУЖНО ЗАПИСЫВАТЬ В ФАЙЛЫ 
            }
        }
    }
}

foreach($entries AS $key=>$array){
    foreach($array as $kitem=>$item){
        $file='require/qq/'.$key.'/'.$kitem.'.php';
        $reg_file='require/qq/'.$key.'/reg/reg_'.$kitem.'.php';

        $write="<?php $";$write.="qq=array(";
        $reg_write=$write;

        foreach($item AS $i){
            $od=explode('=',$i);
            $write.=$od[0]."=>".trim($od[2]).",";
            $reg_write.=$od[0]."=>array(".trim($od[1]).",".trim($od[2])."),";
        }

        $write.="); ?>";
        $reg_write.="); ?>";

        $g=0;
        if(!file_exists($file)){$g=1;}
        $f=fopen($file,'w');
        $rf=fopen($reg_file,'w');

        fwrite($f,$write);
        fwrite($rf,$reg_write);
        fclose($f);
        fclose($rf);
    }
}
```

В цикле for достаются данные из всех документов и записываются в массив entries. Потом этот массив перебирается foreach'ем и расписывает всё по файлам. Всё работает, если берётся 1-15 файлов, то есть for($i=1;$i<15;$i++), но потом выдаёт out of memory.

Как записывать данные в нужный в файл сразу в цикле for, чтобы в начале файле было "`<?php $qq=array(`", а в конце "); ?>"?

Пытаюсь сделать через file_put_contents -- во все файлы записывает одно и то же...

Файлы куда нужно записывать --

```
 $file='require/qq/'.$u.'/'.$ass_arr[1].'.php';<br>
 $reg_file='require/qq/'.$u.'/reg/reg_'.$ass_arr[1].'.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

Начните с упрощения этой груды невнятного кода, в которой разобраться практически нереально.

```
for($i=1;$i<333;$i++){
/* ИМЯ ФАЙЛА */
    $number_length=strlen($i);if($number_length==2){$a='0'.$i;}elseif($number_length==1){$a='00'.$i;}else{$a=$i;}$filename=$fn.$a;
```

Так, наверное, проще и понятней будет?

```
for($i=1;$i<333;$i++)
{
    $filename = sprintf( '%s%03d', $fn, $i );
```

И т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Код точно нужно оптимизировать.

Если быстрое решение нужно и Ваш код работает на 15 файлах, то можете как то помечать уже обработанные файлы (имена в файл писать, удалять, переименовывать), а скрипт на крон например, т. е. вы обработаете все 333 файлов но не за один раз а за несколько (+можно выделять для скрипта больше памяти memory_limit).

> Как записывать данные в нужный в файл сразу в цикле for, чтобы в начале файле было "php $qq=array(", а в конце "); ?>"?

можно например так:

```
$array = array(
    'test1',
    'test2'
);    

$textFile = '<?php ';

ob_start();
var_export($array);
$textArray = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$textFile .= ' $array = '.$textArray.';';
file_put_contents(<файл>, $textFile);
```